# JRip ensemble package for weka

Tags: weka, ensemble-learning

How to install jRip package for ensemble learning in Weka. As part of aggregating collective clustering results through ensemble I need to install jRip package. I couldn't find any relevant link on Web giving access to same.
Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JRip algorithm is bundled with Weka.  Here is a reference to it in Weka's JavaDoc:
http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.stable/weka/classifiers/rules/JRip.html

Here is a download link:
http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/